# Getting a list of all packages from shipping carriers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, fedex

I've been looking at the APIs for UPS, FedEx, USPS, etc, and I can't seem to find any method of pulling all tracking info for a given user. I only see methods that pull info via a tracking number. Has anyone been able to find a way to get at this data? Seems silly to me that these huge carriers wouldn't supply this info in an easy method.

I'm trying to accomplish this in Rails.

Answer (score 2):

We were able to integrate with UPS Quantum View and even with FedEx Insight. These services will give you a list of all inbound and outbound shipments that are billed to your UPS/FedEx account. You can get info on every piece of each shipment: tracking numbers, weight, shipper and recipient info (Company name, city, state, country).

To pull information from UPS Quantum View using their API you will need to obtain a so-called **Access Key**, and you'll need to create **Subscriptions**: one for inbound shipments, one for outbound ones. This can be done on ups.com if you already have a UPS shipping account. You don't have to wait, it's provided instantly. We have a video of how to get the key and set up the subscriptions. It's on [easytag.net](http://easytag.net) in the [Help section](https://easytag.net/help/index.html). The video title is **Obtaining a UPS Access Key**.

When creating API requests to UPS, you'll need to include a key and a subscription name.

Answer (score 0):

UPS has a Quantum View API.  Quantum View is their service that allows tracking, etc by account, not just individual tracking number.  I assume that will get you what you need.  I don't have an account so I can't see their detailed API documentation, so I'm just guessing.

Comment: Jason thanks for the reply. I have looked at Quantum. The issue with that is, I'm going to need to pull data for multiple users. With Quantum apparently you have to signup for a key that takes a few days to get, specific to your account.